# xhr send base64 string and decode it in the server to a file

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, base64

I am trying to to send a base64 encoded img to server,the javascript looks like

```
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest()
var reader=new FileReader()
reader.onloadend=function(e){
xhr.onload=function(e){
alert(xhr.responseText)
}
xhr.open("POST","upload.php");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        //xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.name);
        //xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Type",file.type)
xhr.send(e.target.result)
}
reader.readAsDataURL(file)
},false)
```

In php,looks like this:

```
echo "some response Text";
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
file_put_contents('MyFile.jpg', base64_decode($postdata));
```

And,eventually,the server gets a file **exactly** as big as the sent file,However,it can't be opened
Some one get some ideas?Thanks a lot!

Comment: Open them up with a hex editor and see if there's anything obvious wrong.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
reader.readAsDataURL(file)
```

A data URL is NOT the same as a base64 version of the file. You get extra garbage in it. It looks like this:

```
data:[<MIME-type>][;charset=<encoding>][;base64],<data>
```

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

Try doing a simple regex on it:

```
var data = dataURL.match(/,(.*)$/)[1];
```

Or, in your code,

```
xhr.send(e.target.result.match(/,(.*)$/)[1]);
```

Comment: This worked great - best to strip the extra stuff in Javascript, so that by the time it gets to the server, you have nothing to worry about..